# Implementing NSCoding protocol to send object over to the Java based server

Tags: objective-c, xml-serialization, nskeyedarchiver, nscoding

I have asked a similar question a couple of days ago...
While I have made some progress, I still cant seem to make it work.

Here is what I got up till now:

### customWriteableObj.h:

```
@interface customWriteableObj : NSObject <NSCoding>
@property int integer;
@property NSString * string;
@property BOOL boo;
@end
```

---

### customWriteableObj.m:

```
#import "customWriteableObj.h"

@implementation customWriteableObj
-(id)init
{
    _integer = 117;
    _string = @"aString";
    _boo = YES;
    return self;
}
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    _integer = [aDecoder decodeIntForKey:@"integer"];
    _boo = [aDecoder decodeBoolForKey:@"boo"];
    _string = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"string"];
    return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.string forKey:@"string"];
    [aCoder encodeBool:self.boo forKey:@"boo"];
    [aCoder encodeInteger:self.integer forKey:@"integer"];
}
@end
```

---

### main:

```
customWriteableObj * x = [[customWriteableObj alloc]init];
    NSMutableData *dat = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver* arch1 = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc]initForWritingWithMutableData:dat];
    arch1.outputFormat = NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0;
    [arch1 encodeObject:x forKey:@"tester1"];
    [arch1 finishEncoding];

    [dat writeToFile:@"text.xml";
    customWriteableObj * y = [[customWriteableObj alloc]init];
    y = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"text.xml";
```

---

### Output in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>$archiver</key>
    <string>NSKeyedArchiver</string>
    <key>$objects</key>
    <array>
        <string>$null</string>
        <dict>
            <key>$class</key>
            <dict>
                <key>CF$UID</key>
                <integer>3</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>boo</key>
            <true/>
            <key>integer</key>
            <integer>117</integer>
            <key>string</key>
            <dict>
                <key>CF$UID</key>
                <integer>2</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <string>aString</string>
        <dict>
            <key>$classes</key>
            <array>
                <string>customWriteableObj</string>
                <string>NSObject</string>
            </array>
            <key>$classname</key>
            <string>customWriteableObj</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>$top</key>
    <dict>
        <key>tester1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CF$UID</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>$version</key>
    <integer>100000</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

which doesnt seem to be correct, since I cant see any data here, plus, when I try to read it back I get a nil!
I also need to persist this object to a database on a java based server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance it looks like you are missing the `super` calls in your init methods. This means you overrode these initialization methods and never actually initialize an object. So when you deserialize you would just end up with `nil`. This should fix it:

```
-(id)init
{
   if(self = [super init])
   {
        _integer = 117;
        _string = @"aString";
        _boo = YES;
   }
   return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if(self = [self init])
    {
        _integer = [aDecoder decodeIntForKey:@"integer"];
        _boo = [aDecoder decodeBoolForKey:@"boo"];
        _string = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"string"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**EDIT with JSON serialization example**

Create a method on your custom object class that converts the object into a serializable dictionary. It might look something like:

```
- (NSDictionary *) jsonDictionary
{
    return @{@"integer": @(_integer), @"boo": @(_boo), @"string" : _string};
}
```

Then just call that iteratively on all the objects in your array whenever you are ready to send them over. That might look something like:

```
// Assuming you have an NSArray called customObjects

NSMutableArray *customObjectsJSON = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:customObjects.count];
for(customWriteableObj *object in customObjects)
{
    [customObjectsJSON addObject:[object jsonDictionary]];
}
```

At this point, `customObjectsJSON` is ready to be set as a parameter for a network request. Depending on what other tools you are using you may need to convert it to JSON yourself using `NSJSONSerialization`

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the Nil problem has been solved by the first answer, but I need a way to send this object over to the java based server, do you know how to serialize this object so that it can be recreated at the server side?

Comment: The answer to that is not to use `NSCoding` for sending data to the server. Create an `NSDictionary` with the keys/values you want, convert it to JSON, and send that.

Comment: but I have a whole array of custom objects that need to be written to the disk and then sent over the network to the server... could show me how? perhaps using the example object I have created in the questions?

Comment: I will edit my answer to show how you might create an array of objects for JSON serialization.

Comment: hello @Dima, I tried it out as you suggested, but i get the error message: Invalid type in JSON write (customWriteableObj) I have just have strings and bools in my object!

Comment: can you show me exactly what gives you the error? Did you wrap the bool and integer in `@()` like in my example? You need to do that to convert them to `NSNumbers`.

Comment: I found a problem, I have found a NSAttributedString in there... Is there a way to save it to the JSON?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using an attributed string? can you just convert it to a regular string and use that? It would just be `myAttributedString.string`. If you do need the actual attributes of the string I would also put those in a dictionary manually and send them over along with the string. To my knowledge there is no built in way to convert it all to a dictionary automatically.

Comment: but on the server-side, i should be able to reconstruct the the string with the attributes, plus when my app starts, I need to be able to get the string with attributes from the file...

Comment: All you need to do is decide on what sorts of keys names and values to use for the string attributes and parse them on the server, as well as on the client to rebuild the attributed string when the app starts.

Comment: It seems as though your original question has been answered so you should accept the correct answer (if there is one) and ask a new one. The question you are asking now is outside the scope of the original one.

Answer (score 1):

It looks correct. In the XML you can see your `117` and `aString` values. The XML is a custom format so you generally shouldn't be trying to use it for anything other than storing and reloading.

Your result object when you try to load the archive back in is nil because you are reloading differently than you are archiving (in terms of structure). If you are archiving with `[arch1 encodeObject:x forKey:@"tester1"];` then you need to unarchive with `initForReadingWithData:` and `decodeObjectForKey:`.

Comment: well, I also need to send the object to the java based server, how should I serialize in that case?

Comment: With a specific XML writer, you do not want to use `NSKeyedArchiver` for that. https://www.google.com/search?q=objective-c+xml+writer